# Can I install react native Cli through terminal globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-cli

I want to install react-native cli but I don't where to run this command: `npm install -g react-native-cli`. Do I need to run this command on my macOS terminal or when I will make a directory for my react native app then there I need to run this command in vscode?

Is there any issue if I run this command in my terminal or If I run this in VScode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**React Native** is distributed as two npm packages, **react-native-cli** and **react-native**.

The first one is a lightweight package that should be installed globally (`npm install -g react-native-cli`), while the second one contains the actual React Native framework code and is installed locally into your project when you run react-native init.

Because react-native init calls `npm install react-native`, simply linking your local GitHub clone into npm is not enough to test local changes.
`npm install –g react-native-cli`
· This line installs the npm package **react-native-cli** along with its dependencies(from the npm repository host) inside the globally shared **node_modules** folder.

· Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed. This will also allow you to access the module from the command-line, as the bin is symlinked into a PATH folder (usually usr/local/bin).

Refer below link
https://rlogicaltech.medium.com/how-to-install-react-native-on-mac-step-by-step-guide-1ac822aedd4f

Answer (score 2):

You can run the command **anywhere in the terminal**.
**It will install the react-native-cli globally** as we are specifying the "-g" option in the command.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
npm install -g expo-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

this how I solved it.
npm install -save react-native@latest